# Autotools local destination directory

Tags: autotools

When I run my autotools-generated Makefile with "make" it generates the files in the current directory. I would prefer it to not "pollute" my directory but move the programs to "bin/" (since the source is in "src/")

Is this possible with autotools? (Using autoconf and automake - Not libtool)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mkdir builddir
cd builddir
../foobar-1.2.3/configure --my --options   (or)
/path/to/foobar-1.2.3/configure --my --options
make
make foobar
make check
make install
```

What I usually end up whith when building manually is something like

```
cd foobar-1.2.3
(mkdir _b && cd _b && ../configure --prefix=$PWD/../_i)
make -C _b all check install installcheck
./_i/bin/foobar
vi foo.c bar.c foobar.h
gimp icons/foobar-moo.png
make -C _b install && ./_i/bin/foobar
```

Then I have the whole stuff related to the foobar program inside one directory `foobar-1.2.3`, including source code, built files, and a test installation.

The built files in `foobar-1.2.3/_b` are easily removed with `rm -rf _b`, and the test installation with `rm -rf _i`, in the course of editing the source tree from a shell with current working directory `foobar-1.2.3`.

Of course, you can use a variant of that and move the build/install dirs up one directory: `foobar-1.2.3--b` and `foobar-1.2.3--i` alongside `foobar-1.2.3`.

Comment: That looks good, and I will probably end up using this. But is there no simple way to redirect it by default?

Comment: The make rules Automake creates can compile into the source directory tree and into a kind of "empty mirror" of the source directory tree. There is no third option.

Comment: Well, the default `./configure && make` compiles into the source dir tree. And the `mkdir _b && cd _b && ../configure && make` compiles into a newly created copy of the source dir tree. E.g. `srcmoo/Makefile.am` compiles a `bin_PROGRAM = foo`. Then `_b/srcmoo/Makefile` will be created by the `../configure` run, and the `foo` binary will be written as `_b/srcmoo/foo`.

Either you compile within the source tree, or you compile into that "empty mirror". There is no way to compile stuff from `srcfoo/` to `buildmoo/`.